# jQuery selectors for select / option:selected

Tags: jquery

How should I understand

```
$("select option:selected")
```

in the following code ?

(taken from [here](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/))

```
$("select").change(function() {
   ...
   $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      ...
   });
   ...
})
```

Is it all selected options **in all selects** in the document ?

Is it somehow related to the current select, $(this) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it will refer to all selected options in *all* selects. If you just want to look at the *current* select, you can do something like this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   ...
   $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
      ...
   });
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's selected options from whole document.
You can use `find` to select only from `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

`$("select")` will find all select elements in the document.

and inside the change event you can give

```
$(this).find("option:selected")
```

to get all the option selected for the current select element.

Your statement will fetch all selected options for all select elements inside the document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is correct !

> Is it all selected options in all
>   selects in the document ?

Yes, it does.

> Is it somehow related to the current
>   select, $(this) ?

Yes, `$(this)` is related to current element.

The following code iterates over all the options of all select boxes that are selected:

```
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
   ...
});
```

Therefore, you could do:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   ...
   $(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
      ...
   });
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("select option:selected")` will select an element who is a `option` that has the `selected` attribute set, which is a child of a `select` element.  It will find all selected options on the page.  It is not related to the clicked element `$(this)` - if you wanted it to be, use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) like so: `$(this).find('option:selected')`.

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) then iterates over each selected option on the page doing something with each element.